XML schema validation cannot find declaration with xsd
I have to validate an xml using xsd files.

xsd file companySendType.xsd is:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:CC="http://test.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://test.com" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="companyType.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="companySendType" >
      <xs:complexType>
       ...
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>

Java code:
    SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        
    Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new Source[]{
            new StreamSource(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("companyType.xsd")),
            new StreamSource(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("companySendType.xsd"))
    });
    
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    
    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlToValidate);
    StreamSource streamSource = new StreamSource(stringReader);
    
    validator.validate(streamSource);

And the error I'm getting is:
Cannot find the declaration of element 'CC:companySendType'
The xml is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CC:companySendType version="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://test.com companySendTypev1.18.xsd" xmlns:CC="http://test.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
</CC:companySendType>

I don't understand why it is not working, the xml file seems to be fine.

I checked your xsd and it seems you haven't declare the type of your element CC:companySendType. you can use some default types like:
<xs:element name="companySendType" type="xs:string"/>

or if you have a Complex Type you should define it like bellow example:
<xs:element name="companySendType">
        <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="x1" type="xs:string"/>
                     <xs:element name="x2" type="xs:string"/>
                 </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>


Sorry, I omitted the definition, it is a complex type. I've updated the question
